# Two questions, one answer

Tags: discussion, answers

What should I do, when I've written an answer that would answer two (non-duplicate) questions, equally well?
One example of this would be my answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/52879/5323), which answers the [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52643/5323) that it's posted to perfectly, and should also answer the [related-but-slightly-different](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52643/doctor-recommends-pacemaker-does-the-patient-have-to-listen/52879#comment138616_52643) question [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36741/5323).

What's the best thing to do for this?

- Copy-paste the entire answer to the other question?
- Write a summary of the answer as an answer to the other question, with a link?
- Post a "link-only" answer by the other question, with a link to my first answer?
- Something else?

Comment: @msh210 Thanks! ....I was fairly certain I'd seen this asked before, but I just couldn't find it.

Comment: I've copy pasted entire answers or large segments thereof about 4 or 5 times and hardly anyone has noticed.

Comment: A question about duplicates is a duplicate. :P